# Only 1 upvote/downvote button are working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I put 2 upvote/downvote button, then only the 1st button works. Check [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/12/). Does anyone know, how to fix it?

Comment: duplicate `id`'s are a no no.

Comment: Please add your HTML/JS/CSS to the SO question the next time, as external links may come and go (they may not work in the future).

Comment: You also only have one `storage`, so still wouldn't work even if you fixed the `id` issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given both `buttons` the same `id` while the `id` of each element must be unique.

You can use a `class` to bind the `click` event and find the respective `span` and count the votes and show count of votes in that `span`.

Also you have only one counter. I am not sure but I think if there are two separate buttons there should be two counters, too.

```
$(".buttonup").click(function() {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != votePlus ? votePlus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).next().text(vote);
});
```

Here is downvote button code

```
$(".buttondw").on('click', function () {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != voteMinus ? voteMinus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).prev().text(vote);
});
```

Comment: So should i make a unique ID for each button? and add another javascript for each button? Is this is what you mean? Sorry i am newbie javascripter.

Comment: @tehkc you can either assign each button unique  id or jsut use the code i have provided.

Comment: You can replace it with click event of your `$("#plus").click(function() {`

Comment: ohh thanks mairaj..Now upvote button is fixed.  but downvote is not. See this link https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/18/

Comment: Worked but their one more problem in it. We need to click on upvote button 2 times, in order to cast the vote. See this https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/19/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/16/) is a working version. You must use different ids and handlers for the two section...

Comment: My website is going to have 1000's of vote button. This will make the script long :( Any other solution?